# NodeJS Variable Scope

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, mongodb

I'm very, very new to the whole NodeJS stack, and I'm trying to rough up a simple login system for practice.

Jumping to my question,

***app.js***

```
...
var mongoose = require( 'mongoose' );
var templates = require( './data/inc.js' ); // includes schema structures
...
```

---

***user.js - included in inc.js***

```
...
module.exports =
{
    "Schema" : new exports.mongoose.Schema({
      "uid": mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      "username": { type:String, unique:true },
      "alias": String,
      "credentials":
      {
        "salt": String,
        "password": String,
        "key": String
      },
      "profile":
      {
        "age": { type: Number, min: 18 }
      },
      "last_login": Date,
      "updated": { type: Date, default: Date.now }
    })
}
...
```

The 'user.js' script above will not work because it doesn't have access to the mongoose object variable instantiated in the 'app.js' script. In PHP any included/required scripts would be able to access variables from the parent script, but in NodeJS as I know it for example I have to re-require/state the mongoose variable in order to create my schema tree.

***user.js***

```
...
* var mongoose = require( 'mongoose' ); // must include in script to use mongoose object

module.exports
{
   ...
}
...
```

Is there any work-around that will allow me the same scope access as PHP?

Comment: Why don't you want to use `require('mongoose')`? What's the problem with it?

Comment: I mean you could set a global variable like `global.mongoose = require("mongoose");`, but that would be ugly.

Comment: There's no harm in requiring mongoose in each schema file. I would consider that normal. It won't hinder performance due to how requiring modules in node.js work. You also do not have to re-connect to mongoose inside of each schema, once is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that there are workarounds, but you really don't want to use them, ever, ever, except for things which you want to hack into the global scope of all running modules in your application up to and including all dependencies (mongoose) and all of ITS dependencies.

**override.js**

`global.thisIsNowAvailable = true;`

**flaky-file.js**

`if (thisIsNowAvailable) { /* ... */ }`

**index.js**

```
require("./override");
require("./flaky-file");
```

The same will work for overriding methods on global prototypes, et cetera.

Unless your library is super-awesome and is intended to intercept, parse and interpret code at require-time

```
require("babel/register"); // all loaded modules can now be written in ES6
```

doing this for other reasons leads to horrible code-bases...

**broken-index.js**

```
require("flaky-file");
require("override");
// you might have just attempted to reference a variable that doesn't exist, 
// thrown an error and crashed your entire server
// (not just a single connection, like PHP...  ...the entire server went down,
// for everyone, and it has to be restarted).
```

Think of modules as separate function scopes.
It's really simple to do something like:

**needs-mongoose.js**

```
function doSomeInitWithMongoose (db) { /* ... */ }
function doSomeRuntimeWithMongoose (db, params) { /* ... */ }

module.exports = mongoose => {
    doSomeInitWithMongoose(mongoose);

    return {
      run: params => {
        /* ... app is run here ... */
        doSomeRuntimeWithMongoose(mongoose, params);
      }
    };
};
```

**configures-mongoose.js**

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
function configure (db, cfg) { /* ... */ return db; }

module.exports = config => {
    var configuredDB = configure(mongoose, config);
    return configuredDB;
};
```

**main.js**

```
// to support arrow functions and other awesome ES6, including ES6 modules
require("babel/register");

var config = require("./mongoose-config");
var db = require("./configures-mongoose")(config);
var app = require("./needs-mongoose")(db);

app.run({ /* ... */ });
```

## EDIT

Updated the last few files to be a structurally-correct pseudo-program (which does absolutely nothing, of course);

Of course, if `index.js` or `server.js` were to `require("babel/register");` and then load `main.js` (without the Babel include in it), all of the `require` statements south of Babel could be written as ES6 modules, without issue.

**server.js**

```
require("babel/register");
require("./es6-main");
```

**es6-main.js**

```
import config from "./mongoose-config";
import configureDB from "./configures-mongoose";
import loadApp from "./needs-mongoose";

const db = configureDB(config);
const app = loadApp(db);

app.run({ /* ... */ });
```

Note that now I'm naming the functions I was originally returning, because in JS when you return a function, you can immediately call it...

```
getFunc( config )( data );
```

...but you can't act immediately on `import` statements.

Rule of thumb is that if you're going to export an object to the outside world, it should have 0 external dependencies, or all external dependencies will be set up later, by setters of some kind:

```
var utils = require("./utils"); // doesn't need any information
utils.helperFunc(data);
```

or

```
var catsAndPorn = true;
var internets = [];
var SeriesOfTubes = require("series-of-tubes");
var internet = new SeriesOfTubes( catsAndPorn );
internets.push( internet );
```

or

```
var bigOlFramework = require("big-ol-framework");
bigOlFramework.setDBPool( myDBCluster );
http.createServer( bigOlFramework.connectionHandler ).listen( 8080 );
```

None require outside information for their actual init (though may require their own internal dependencies).

If you want to return something which does rely on external init, either export a factory/constructor, or export a function, which accepts your config/data, and then returns what you want, after an init sequence.

## EDIT 2

The last piece of advice here is that as far as `mongoose` usage goes, or Gulp, to a similar extent, or several routers...
...when you want to have a single file which registers its contents to a registry, or requires a core-component, to be able to return something, the pattern in Node which makes the most sense is to return a function which then does the init

```
var Router = require("router");
var router = new Router( );

require("./routes/login")(router);
require("./routes/usesrs")(router);
require("./routes/articles")(router);
```

Where "./routes/articles.js" might look like

```
import ArticlesController from "./../controller/articles"; // or wherever
var articles = new ArticlesController();
module.exports = router => {
    router.get("/articles", ( ) => articles.getAll( ));
    router.post("/articles", ( ) => articles.create( ));
};
```

So if you were looking to structure ORM based on schema, you might do similar:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Users = require("./schema/users")(mongoose);
```

where "./schema/users" looks like:

```
module.exports = mongoose => {
    return new mongoose.Schema({ /* ... */ });
};
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Getting a clearer understanding of how it all boils down now.

Comment: @JohnNolette No worries. I updated to tack some stuff onto the end, to make those examples more useful, and to tack some ES6 in, as it's really something new people should be onboarding into, now, as well.  It's not 100% supported in browsers/platforms yet, but it is happily transpiled by tools like Babel, on either.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just do this?

```
var mongoose = require( 'mongoose' );
...
"Schema" : new mongoose.Schema({
```

Instead of:

```
exports.mongoose.Schema // I'm not sure where you got `exports.mongoose` from.
```

Also you don't have to use the `.js` when requiring like:

```
var templates = require( './data/inc' );
```

### Edit

I believe you can't do it like PHP. Also the requires are cached so no need to worry about `re` requiring.

Comment: He knows he can do that. It's in his question.